# Deployment fails with a 504

Tags: deployment, cloud-foundry, swisscomdev

I'm trying to deploy an application to the Swisscom App Cloud from the console. It reports progress until at the end, an 504 without further explanation is reported:

```
Updating app helloclass-fe-develop in org UCID-Bern Team / space HELLOCLASS-TEST as christian.cueni@iterativ.ch...
OK

Uploading helloclass-fe-develop...
FAILED
Error processing app files: Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 504, error code: 0, message:
```

The log of the app reports that the app has been updated:

```
2017-01-03 09:37:39 [RTR/0] OUT helloclass-develop.scapp.io - [03/01/2017:08:37:39.584 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0 594 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.75 Safari/537.36 Google Favicon" 66.249.93.201:50868 10.0.18.35:64341 x_forwarded_for:"83.76.152.96" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:8a8adcc7-9e97-4bd9-4492-68e92883ee3d response_time:0.001739219 app_id:310166b4-f3a6-4168-a9ac-530e45dbfb10 app_index:0
2017-01-03 09:37:39 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 83.76.152.96, 66.249.93.201, 66.249.93.201 - - - [03/Jan/2017:08:37:39 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 606
2017-01-03 10:05:50 [API/2] OUT Updated app with guid 310166b4-f3a6-4168-a9ac-530e45dbfb10 ({"name"=>"helloclass-fe-develop"})
2017-01-03 10:57:15 [API/1] OUT Updated app with guid 310166b4-f3a6-4168-a9ac-530e45dbfb10 ({"state"=>"STOPPED"})
2017-01-03 10:57:15 [CELL/0] OUT Exit status 0
2017-01-03 10:57:15 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 0
2017-01-03 10:57:15 [CELL/0] OUT Destroying container
2017-01-03 10:57:15 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully destroyed container
2017-01-03 10:57:16 [API/1] OUT Updated app with guid 310166b4-f3a6-4168-a9ac-530e45dbfb10 ({"state"=>"STARTED"})
2017-01-03 10:57:16 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
2017-01-03 10:57:16 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
2017-01-03 10:57:17 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
2017-01-03 10:57:19 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
```

In spite of those messages which would indicate that the app has been updated, I still see the old version of the app being served.

---

**EDIT**

After running the command with the `-v` parameter, I see that the reason for the failure is a gateway timeout:

```
RESPONSE: [2017-01-03T13:32:39+01:00]
HTTP/1.1 504 Gateway Timeout
Connection: close
Content-Length: 176
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 03 Jan 2017 12:32:39 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Vcap-Request-Id: 3ac831ef-e70b-4f4e-7c56-e308806f039e
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block

<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>

FAILED
Error processing app files: Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 504, error code: 0, message:
```

Is this something cloudfoundry specific or rather related to Swisscom AppCloud? Are there cloudfoundry inherent timeout limits?

Comment: How big is your application, how long does it it hang at `Uploading helloclass-fe-develop...` and have you tested your bandwidth to your CF provider?  It might just be that your app is taking too long to upload.  As @dkoper mentioned, the gorouters have a hard timeout for all incoming requests.  It defaults to 900s, but your provider may set it to something larger / smaller.  If you do some math on the request / response date headers from the trace output you should be able to see how long its waiting and if that might be hitting a timeout.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I was uploading from the root directory instead of the build/dist folder. This caused the timeout..

Answer (score 2):

You can run `cf push` with `-v` or enable CF_TRACE to see more of the interaction of the CLI with your CF endpoint.
The error message looks similar to https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1042: the Cloud Controller could not complete a request in time and the router that routed the API request to Cloud Controller did not wait any longer and returned the 504 (Gateway timeout) to the CLI.

The trace should tell you which API call timed out.
The CLI aborted the operation there, while the Cloud Controller may have completed the operation successfully, eventually.

I would have thought the operations the CLI would perform here are:

1. send a list of files in your app and their checksums for resource matching (so it can skip uploading unmodified app bits that the CC cached from a previous push)
2. upload app files
3. (re)start app (which includes staging)
4. poll & wait until an app instance returns that it's running

From your CLI output I assume the first operation timed out, so not clear how your app was restarted.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Verbosity revealed the source. See edit in my question.

Comment: We already knew a 504 Gateway timeout was returned from the original message. What would be interesting to see next is the API request that received the 504. You didn't include it in the trace: what was the request logged prior to the 504 response? (you can exclude the long payload if it's a call to the resource matching API)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support! I was uploading from the root directory instead of the build/dist folder. This caused the timeout..